# Jpa OneToOne shared primary key half works

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I have SpringBoot 2.1.3 and Java 8 application. Building DB with JPA I have 3 table in one to one relationship. Suppose the tables is the follows:

```
@Entity
@Data //lombok
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Address address;
}
```

And then:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @MapsId
  private User user;
}
```

That's works.. and it is the best way to do (this exactly example is taken from documentation).

If I start the application the DB is created and if I tried to add entities all works well. The model created follows:

[image: Thw two table with onetoone relationships]

Now I want to add a Country object to my address Entities (for example) and I modified the Entities as follows:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 private Long id;

 @OneToOne
 @MapsId
 private User user;

 @OneToOne
 @MapsId
 private Country country;
}
```

And Country Entities:

```
@Entity
@Data 
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Address address;
}
```

The application still starts, the DB is created and the model follows:

[image: final model]

But if I try to save a User as follows:

```
User user = new User();
Address address = new Address();
Country country = new Country();

user.setAddress(address);
address.setUser(user);

address.setCountry(country);
country.setAddress(address);

userRepository.save(user);
```

I obtain the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'country_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Anyway I solve the issue removing @MapsId and added @JoinColumn but I would like to understand what's wrong.

P.S.: I'm using MySQL 5.7 with InnoDB dialect (setting on application.properties)

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works only with one [@MapsId](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) annotation. Using two is causing that country id is not inserted:

```
insert into Country (id) values (?)
insert into Users (id) values (?)
insert into Address (user_id) values (?)
```

Comment: Then I was right.. Thank's a lot for your patience!